# how to import a 3D human model from MakeHuman into android?

Tags: android

I created a Humanmodel in MakeHuman. I want to import it into android Eclipse?

How do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with MakeHuman but almost certainly it can export it to one of popular 3d format (3ds, etc). Then you run one of 3d modelling tools, load your model and export it to "c" array. Some of them can do it out of the box and the others may require plugins.

At the end of day you will have c array with faces and normals defined. Looks like this:

```
union Vector3
{
        struct { float X, Y, Z; };
        struct { float R, G, B; };
};

typedef union Vector3 Vector3;

struct Vertex {
        Vector3 position;
        Vector3 normal;
};

typedef struct Vertex Vertex;

const Vertex PawnData[] = {
    {/*v:*/{-0.243664, 0.387085, -0.000968}, /*n:*/{-0.997284, 0.073305, 0.000000} },
    {/*v:*/{-0.256456, 0.214871, 0.082218}, /*n:*/{-0.936430, 0.174566, 0.304270} },
    {/*v:*/{-0.231469, 0.387085, 0.074100}, /*n:*/{-0.946898, 0.093417, 0.307657} },
    {/*v:*/{0.074727, 0.387085, -0.232293}, /*n:*/{0.307657, 0.093570, -0.946867} },
....
};
```

Next it is not difficult to convert it to java and load in your app as VBO.

This is the simplest if you have your 3d objects static.

Btw, you definitely will face the performance issues because normally all 3d models are too heavy, that is, having too many faces needlessly. To balance their geometry you will need one more tool. I used one called "Balancer" from www.atangeo.com. It can make number of faces 10x less without noticeable visual change.

Comment: The model is saved into two extensions (.MHM) and (.THUMB).Other extensions in MakeHuman Mesh formats are collada,blender exchange,film box,wave front,ogre 3d,MD 5,stereolithography.

Comment: You need to chose the format that has ability to be converted to c-char. If you know that 3d studio can do it - then save to 3ds. I don't remember what I used.